# Creating object with dynamic key

Tags: javascript, json

I have to create a object key based on some dynamic value .
Here the value of `str` will from user to user. The user enters the value of str.
I want to use `str` value entered by user to create Object.

```
var str = $('#inputValue');

var obj = new Object();
obj.assignment = new Object();
obj.assignment.name= "assignmentName";
obj.assignment.str = new Object();
```

Comment: Duplicate of ~ 1000 questions.

Comment: I am confused - what the first `str` is for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the brackets syntax:

```
obj.assignment[str] = new Object();
```

Side note: you can use the shortcut `{}` to create new objects. For example:

```
obj.assignment[str] = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

New Object:

```
obj.assignment[str] = {};
```